# C#/WPF Using async and await but the UI thread is still blocked

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous, async-await

I'm having this simple code:

```
private async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var progress = new Progress<int>();

    progress.ProgressChanged += (a, b) =>
    {
        this.progressBar.Value = b;
    };

    // this is blocking
    await this.LongRunOpAsync(filepath, progress);

    // this is not blocking
    // await this.LongRunOpAsync(filepath, null);
}

public Task LongRunOpAsync(string filename, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var ops = new LongOps())
        {
            ops.LongRunOp(filename, progress);
        }
    });
}
```

Once I click my button the UI is still blocked from the long running operation. If I don't use the Progress and instead give my long running operation **null** as the second parameter the UI isn't blocking. I'm quite sure this "error" is due to some misunderstanding I have about async/await and threads.

Comment: I think you need to use async and await in the LongRunOpAsync method, not in the Button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown won't block the UI thread.

In fact, as shown, it doesn't need async/await - so I'm assuming this is not the actual code.

You need to look at what `ops.LongRunOp` does with the `progress` function.

I suspect it marshals `progress` back to the UI thread - so it can access UI controls.

If it does this too often and too quickly, it will swamp the UI thread and make the app unresponsive.

Comment: Which is true. ops.LongRunOp reports very often which seems to be the actual problem.